# How to override Email Header and Footer through module in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, email-templates, magento2.2.2, php-7, header

I want to override magento email template file.

- app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/Magento_Email/email/header.html
- app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/Magento_Email/email/footer.html

Answer (score 0):

Create a **requirejs-config.js** in the below location:

> /app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

and add the below code to **requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
          'Magento_Email/email/header.html': 'Vendor_Module/email/header.html',
          'Magento_Email/email/footer.html': 'Vendor_Module/email/footer.html',
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, In my case email header is dynamic according to the stores, any solution of it.

Comment: Create different headers and footers with different name then assign those to your stores should work.